# Proper use of "vernacular"

Tags: grammaticality

Is this proper use of the word *vernacular*?

> Wow! *Curmudgeons* is a cool word! I'm going to add it to my **vernacular**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an incorrect use of *[vernacular](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vernacular)*; it really should be *[vocabulary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vocabulary)*.  The reason why this is incorrect is that *vernacular* refers to the vocabulary of common words shared by a group of people.  You cannot add new words to it at the drop of a hat.

It may be misleading to say *my* vernacular; it is important to realize that this means the vernacular you *share*, not the corpus of words you personally ordinarily use.  Your personal word list is called your *vocabulary*.

You can see the incorrect way in use by googling ["add it to my vernacular"](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22add%20it%20to%20my%20vernacular%22) (47 results), and the correct way by googling ["add it to my vocabulary"](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22add%20it%20to%20my%20vocabulary%22) (266).

Comment: i agree vocabulary is probably more clear, but i was still curious.

Comment: I think using *vernacular* in this manner is an eggcorn of sorts: it starts with the same letter as the appropriate word (*vocabulary*) and it means something in the same ballpark, so people think it's ok. However, unless you're Lord High Vernacular Police or something, you can't add words to a vernacular, not even if you happen to speak that vernacular.

Comment: that's a good way of putting it Martha, thank you!

Comment: The Google link is a typical case of misleading *about nnnn results*. It starts off claiming there are **about 49,900 results**, but when you page through them it turns out there are only 44 - so it's not "oft-used" at all. You're quite right the standard word is *vocabulary* (I wouldn't have a problem with *lexicon*, or even *ideolect*), but I can't bring myself to upvote while you've got "oft-used" in there!

Answer (score 8):

This is not the correct use. You're assuming that you can add the word "Curmudgeons" among a group of people, not just yourself.

Answer (score 3):

A vernacular is the language spoken by a certain group or people living in a certain area (see [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/vernacular) and [CALD](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/vernacular?q=vernacular)). Use in your example sentence is inappropriate unless it is used humorously or metaphorically.